# Excel Index Match - Largest, 2nd Largest, 3rd Largest without duplicate Matches

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

Really appreciate any help. I'm trying to match the highest, 2nd highest, and 3rd highest scoring sections from a list without duplicates. But I am stuck with how to index the results.

Right now because multiple sections may have a score of 100%, if there are two sections with 100%, match will immediately index the first result, instead of the next unique result.

**Current Formulas:**

```
=INDEX(D6:D14,MATCH(LARGE(E6:E14,1),E6:E14,0))
=INDEX(D6:D14,MATCH(LARGE(E6:E14,2),E6:E14,0))
=INDEX(D6:D14,MATCH(LARGE(E6:E14,3),E6:E14,0))
=INDEX(D6:D14,MATCH(SMALL(E6:E14,1),E6:E14,0))
=INDEX(D6:D14,MATCH(SMALL(E6:E14,2),E6:E14,0))
=INDEX(D6:D14,MATCH(SMALL(E6:E14,3),E6:E14,0))
```

**Current Data**

Data

| Description | Score (%) |
| --- | --- |
| RED | 100 |
| BLUE | 30 |
| GREEN | 100 |
| WHITE | 100 |
| ORANGE | 99 |
| PURPLE | 75 |
| CYAN | 75 |
| BLACK | 80 |
| GRAY | 37 |

Answers

| Rank | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Highest | RED |
| 2nd Highest | RED |
| 3rd Highest | RED |
| Lowest | BLUE |
| 2nd Lowest | GRAY |
| 3rd Lowest | PURPLE |

**Desired Data:**

```
2nd Highest to be Green
3rd Highest to be White
```

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: And does the order in the table matter when a tie?  For example Cyan and Purple are tied for the 3rd Lowest, does it matter which is returned?

Comment: Version 2109 Build 14430.20306
I think it's just normal Office 365

Comment: Prefer from top down because the bottom sections typically get 100%, but It's not the end of the world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Office 365 we can use SORT and CHOOSE the top three and bottom three:

```
=LET(
    rng,    A2:B10,
    rws,    ROWS(rng),
    INDEX(SORT(rng,2,-1),CHOOSE({1;2;3;4;5;6},1,2,3,rws,rws-1,rws-2),1))
```

The top three will go in order of entry if tied, the bottom three will go from the bottom up if tied.

[image]

Comment: This looks really good, but I'm having trouble entering it. My actual data is: from B47 to N:500. The row names / identifiers are in B. The scores are in N. And there are frequently blank lines.
An actual formula from the file is =INDEX(B47:B500,MATCH(MIN(N47:N500),N47:N500,0))

Comment: change `rng,    A2:B10,` to `rng,    CHOOSE({1,2},B47:B500,N47:N500),`

Comment: The formula won't get the lowest values if there are blank cells in-between. Any way to filter out non-zeros? It also doesn't work with merged cells (#spill error). Definitely harder to implement than I envisioned. It 100% works on my test sheet like above, but not the actual document yet.
Maybe this is easier if I just provide the specific B & N cells?
N47,N85,N141,N163,N187,N207,N231,N262,N283,N308,N327,N353,N379,N413,N437,N465,N500

Comment: Tried this (getting closer):
=LET(rng,CHOOSE({1,2},B47,B85,B141,B163,B187,B207,B231,B262,B283,B308,B327,B353,B379,B413,B437,B465,B500,N47,N85,N141,N163,N187,N207,N231,N262,N283,N308,N327,N353,N379,N413,N437,N465,N500),rws,ROWS(rng),INDEX(SORT(rng,2,-1),CHOOSE({1;2;3;4;5;6},1,2,3,rws,rws-1,rws-2,1)))

Comment: @Greg you really should have provided an example set that shows a true example of your data structure.  At this point it would be better if you asked a new question with the new criteria.  And show how you tried to modify the formula to fit that new criteria.  Both my answer and JvdV answer, answered this question as is.  You should choose one to be the correct answer for this scenario and ask a new question with the added criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there would at least always be six values, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(X,SORT(A2:B10,2,-1),Y,SEQUENCE(6),INDEX(X,IF(Y<4,Y,COUNTA(X)/2-(Y-4)),1))
```